# SDL2 and 3D Rendering

Tags: opengl, 3d, sdl, sdl-2

Does SDL2 have the capability to render things in 3D (i.e. make cubes, spheres, etc.) without the use of OpenGL, or does it only have 2D capabilities?

Answer (score 6):

Your question would be better off on [GameDev Stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) but to simply answer your question: SDL2 itself has **no** capabilities to render 3D objects. This is also stated in [SDLs about](https://www.libsdl.org/index.php) page:

> Simple DirectMedia Layer is a cross-platform development library designed to provide low level access to audio, keyboard, mouse, joystick, and *graphics hardware via OpenGL and Direct3D*

SDL provides some functions to help you ease the use of OpenGL, but you'll have to learn and use OpenGL to allow rendering 2D and 3D vector graphics.

A good tutorial that I'd recommend on the basics of SDL is [this](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/) site. It only has some chapters related to the use of OpenGL, but if you haven't used SDL much, this is a great start.

Comment: You're correct, but the quote is unrelated. *"access to ... graphics hardware via OpenGL and Direct3D"* means that SDL2 can use OpenGL and Direct3D under the hood to render primitives.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Fair enough, that could be understood in an ambiguous manner.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the wiki has to say:

> [2D Accelerated Rendering](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryRender)
>
> For advanced functionality like particle effects or actual 3D you should use SDL's OpenGL/Direct3D support or one of the many available 3D engines.

SDL does not aim to provide a 3D API, but gives you some support for other well-known APIs like OpenGL and Direct3D.

Note that SDL2 also provides [Vulkan support](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryVulkan).